# Linq query returning exception

Tags: c#, .net, linq

So I have this piece of code :

```
var imageList = (from stepImages in xrmContext.SdkMessageProcessingStepImageSet
       where stepImages.IsNotNull() && stepImages.SdkMessageProcessingStepId.Id == tempPluginStep.steps.Id
                select new
                {
                     stepImages

                }).ToList();
```

The problem with it is that it's returning a "Sequence contains no element" exception and I though .ToList would return an empty IEnumerable if there was no elements selected. What seem to be the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try replacing this:

```
select new
{
   stepImages
}
```

With:

```
select stepImages
```

Comment: I wouldn't expect that to have any impact on the error involved. Sure, it's a good idea anyway, but I don't expect it to fix anything.

Comment: what does stepImages.IsNotNull() method do? I guess the problem may be caused by it.

Comment: It doesn't have any impact on the exception but thanks anyway.

Comment: The combination of the answer and allentranks comment did it for me. I had to make both change just one wouldn't fix my problem.